# Java GUI (SWT) - display text while performing other actions like reading that text

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, event-handling, swt

I have is a java class that reads a text file. For each line read, this class (called `X`), writes a record into a database.

This works without any GUI, only from a linux shell.

I'd like to have a nice GUI where, when that X class reads one single line (and so on for every line), it can display a popup or similar (`Jframe`, `Jtable`, etc.) and ask the user if that line has to be written to database.

How do I let those two classes (the `databaseSaver` and the `GUIdisplayer`) interoperate? It's not necessary to parallelize the work, it could be something like:

For each line:

1. read a line (by class `databaseSaver`)
2. tell to GUI to display and ask what to do (maybe send an event to the class `GUIdisplay`)
3. listen to the response and do what to do (by class `databaseSaver`)

Is it possible to attach a GUI Event Listener to actions of a class?

Comment: Use [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html), and edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that shows your approach..

Answer (score -1):

I assume you are reading the values in a loop. Inside that loop, make a call to the GUI and pass the text with a confirm yes/no option. On yes, call a method to insert into the database. On no, continue to the next line.

Am I missing something?